# How to make it Responsive popover the customized popover template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make it responsive because when make it smaller the browser the popover was moving and not position in a right place or stick in button in short its not responsive.

kindly please help me for my new beginning please...

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn  btn-default btn-light text-center my-popover"
data-html='true'
data-trigger="focus"
data-container="body" 
data-template='
      <div class="popover" role="tooltip">
          <div class="arrow"></div>
          <div class="popover-top"></div>
          <div class="popover-content"></div>
      </div>' 
data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="bottom" 
data-content='<h4 id="pop-title">Description</h4>
                 <div class="row pop-content">
                    <ul id="pop-ul" class="list-unstyled col-md-12"> 
                       <li id="pop-li">Reponsive Layout</li>
                       <li id="pop-li">Less Effort</li>
                       <li id="pop-li">Smooth User Experience</li>
                       <li id="pop-li">Statics</li>
                       <li id="pop-li">User Friendly website</li>
                     </ul>
                   </div>
                '>Learn More</button>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {

var orig = $.fn.popover,
    proto = $.extend({}, $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype);

$.fn.popover = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        orig.call($(this), options);
        if (typeof options.hide == 'function') {
            $(this).data('bs.popover').hide = function() {
                console.log(proto);
                options.hide.call(this.$tip, this);
                proto.hide.call(this);
            };
        }
    });
}

})();

$('.my-popover').popover({
placement: 'bottom',
hide: function() {
    $(this).animate({marginTop: -10}, function() {
        $(this).css({marginTop: 10});
    });
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
.popover {
position:  absolute !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1060;
display: none;
width: 250px !important;
padding: 0px;
text-align: left;
white-space: normal;
background-color: #fff !important;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #42dca3;
border: 1px solid #42dca3;
border-radius: 0px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 }

.popover.bottom {
margin-top: 10px;
 }

.popover-title {
 padding: 8px 14px;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 18px;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
 }

.popover-top {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #42dca3 !important;
}

.popover-content {
  padding: 9px 20px;
}

.popover > .arrow,
.popover > .arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.popover > .arrow {
  border-width: 11px;
}

.popover > .arrow:after {
  content: "";
  border-width: 10px;
}

.popover.bottom > .arrow {
  top: -11px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-color: ##42dca3;
  border-bottom-color: ##42dca3;
}

.popover.bottom > .arrow:after {
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  content: " ";
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #42dca3;
 }
```